# Drawing Graphics Disappear in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, graphics, draw, paint

I have a simple program that you can draw on the screen with FillEllipse and FillRectangle. My problem is that when you drag another window over even a small portion of the screen, that part will be erased. This happens when you drag the other window over, let go, and drag it back off. Is there any way to fix this?

```
Dim MyFormObject As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
        Select Case shape
            Case "Ellipse"
                MyFormObject.FillEllipse(brush, e.X - CInt(brushWidth / 2), e.Y - CInt(brushHeight / 2), brushWidth, brushHeight)
            Case "Rectangle"
                MyFormObject.FillRectangle(brush, e.X - CInt(brushWidth / 2), e.Y - CInt(brushHeight / 2), brushWidth, brushHeight)
        End Select
```

Comment: Are you drawing directly to the screen (hdc 0) or to your own form?

Comment: edited the answer below, instead of creating a new Graphics each time you'll need to draw to a persistent graphics like a pictureBox. Alternatively you can redraw on every paint event but that could get expensive.

Answer (score 5):

You can put a PictureBox control on your form and draw to that instead and it won't be erased when other windows paint over it:

do this once, on form_load or something:

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
```

to draw:

```
Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image).FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100);
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

Comment: This fixed it for my friend.  he was using Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle) in his form load.  After changing to use the FromImage(pictureBox1.Image) it worked!  It now shows the graphics on form load without it disappearing!

Answer (score 4):

You need to do all of your drawing in the `Paint` event, which fires each time your control gets repainted.

Comment: What exactly is the Paint event, and how would I do my drawing in it? I'm new to graphics

Answer (score 1):

The following code allows you to draw a rectangle with the mouse (click and drag). Add a `PictureBox` to a form.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private mpntMouseDown As Point

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim w As Integer = PictureBox1.Width
    Dim h As Integer = PictureBox1.Height
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(w, h, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
      Dim rct As New RectangleF(0, 0, w, h)
      Dim b As Brush = New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(rct, Color.White, Color.Blue, 0)
      g.FillRectangle(b, rct)
      g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, New RectangleF(CInt(0.1 * w), CInt(0.2 * h), CInt(0.8 * w), CInt(0.6 * h)))
      g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, New RectangleF(CInt(0.1 * w) + 1, CInt(0.2 * h) + 1, CInt(0.8 * w) - 2, CInt(0.6 * h) - 2))
      Dim sft As New StringFormat
      sft.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
      sft.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
      g.DrawString("Sample Image", New Font(System.Drawing.FontFamily.GenericSerif, 14, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Red, rct, sft)
    End Using
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp
  End Sub

  Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
      mpntMouseDown = e.Location
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    If mpntMouseDown = Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image, Bitmap)
      Dim rct As New Rectangle
      If mpntMouseDown.X < e.X Then
        rct.X = mpntMouseDown.X
        rct.Width = e.X - mpntMouseDown.X + 1
      Else
        rct.X = e.X
        rct.Width = mpntMouseDown.X - e.X + 1
      End If
      If mpntMouseDown.Y < e.Y Then
        rct.Y = mpntMouseDown.Y
        rct.Height = e.Y - mpntMouseDown.Y + 1
      Else
        rct.Y = e.Y
        rct.Height = mpntMouseDown.Y - e.Y + 1
      End If
      g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rct)
    End Using
    mpntMouseDown = Nothing
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If the PictureBox is covered up by another object, such as another form or another application, all the drawing you do here will disappear.  All painting of the form or control should happen in the OnPaint method or Paint event.

Comment: That's peculiar. When I test the code, covering up the form does not lose the drawing, but minimising the form does.

Comment: I have edited my answer to resolve the issue raised by Chris Dunaway

Answer (score 0):

@SLaks already told you to do all painting in the OnPaint method. Here's a little more information. If you're trying to draw on a form, you would override the OnPaint method and do all your painting using the Graphics instance that is passed into the method. Here is more information on the topic:

- [How to use the CreateGraphics method](https://web.archive.org/web/20141006045615/http://bobpowell.net/creategraphics.aspx)
- [CreateGraphics. A boon or a curse?](https://web.archive.org/web/20131226033137/http://bobpowell.net/picturebox.aspx)

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, Me.ClientRectangle)

End Sub
```